# unable to access the controller in jasmine

Tags: angularjs, typescript, text, jasmine

angularjs && Typescript Controller

---

```
   module app.controller {
   class MainCtrl {
   static $inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$interval', '$http', 'unityService',
   'adalAuthenticationService', '$location', '$window', 'analyticsService', 'homePageSetting',
   'unityCommonService', '$timeout', '$cookies', '$routeParams', '$compile', '$filter'];
   }
   constructor(
   private $scope,
   private $rootScope,
   private $interval,
   private $http,
   private unityService: app.services.unityService,
   private adalAuthenticationService,
   private $location,
   private $window,
   private analyticsService,
   private homePageSetting,
   private unityCommonService,
   private $timeout,
   private $cookies,
   private $routeParams,
   private $compile,
   private $filter

       ) { }
   angular.module('UnityApp').controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);
   }

   Jasmine Test For Controller

   beforeEach(function () { angular.module("UnityApp") });

   it("should make a string more exciting", inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
   var controller =
   $controller('MainCtrl', {
   $scope: $rootScope.$new(), // scope 
   });
    //controller got undefined error when i access the controller ?? i tried many ways but i m unable to get the controller 
   }));
```

i m unable to access the scope in MainCtrl

---

Comment: i m using module level implementation in typescript .is it differentiate regular implementation of instantiate controller in jasmine ??

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is create the scope and assign it to a local variable before you init the controller.

```
it("should make a string more exciting", inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {

  var $myScope = $rootScope.$new();

  $controller('MainCtrl', {
    $scope: $myScope
  });

}));
```

You'll then be able to access the controller scope in $myScope.

Comment: still not working . $controller is not a function got undefined error